# Keep getting "Request header field authorization is not allowed" on hapi server

Tags: node.js, cors, authorization, hapi.js, hapi

I have tried every combinations I found on the internet for hapi cors settings, but I kept getting:

```
... has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization
is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

The server seems to detect OPTIONS request with 204 and it is working fine without Authorization header.

Please help me, I'm using Hapi v21.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Apologize for this question.

It seems that I have this OPTIONS with wildcard route handler:

```js
        method: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "PATCH"],
        path: "/{path*}",
        handler: (request, h) => {
          return h.response().header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Content-Type, User-Agent');
        }
```

I realized this after reading:
https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/2860#issuecomment-149789201

So for anyone having this issue, please check your OPTIONS routes